# adding ripple effect along with a line divider

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view, each item in it is represented as a linear layout. I am trying to add ripple effect to each item.

Linear Layout looks something like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/list_item"
style="@style/ItemStyle"
android:paddingLeft="6dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
```

ItemStyle in the above layout is given as

```
<style name="ItemStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/item_background</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/item_height</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">1dp</item>
</style>
```

@drawable/item_background is given as

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/primary" />
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_divider_background" />
</selector>
```

The problem is that if i change `android:background` from `@drawable/item_background` to `?attr/selectableItemBackground`, i am able to get the ripple effect but the line divider, `@drawable/item_divider_background` mentioned inside the `@drawable/item_background` is not appearing. Can someone tell what is the workaround to add both the divider and the ripple effect.

Comment: why not add a a line in last of `LinearLayout` and keep `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`

Comment: Along with the line divider I want to use the other attributes like color on state pressed, state mentioned as mentioned in  @drawable/item_background.

Comment: Along with setting color of different states, adding line dividers I want to add ripple effect as well.

Comment: check my answer. It can be achieved using external library

Answer (score 0):

One workaround can be to add the divider programmatically using item decorator-

```
public class MyDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration  {
private Drawable mDivider;

public MyDecorator(Context context) {
    mDivider = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, org.itm.xoinfo.R.drawable.simpleline);
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);

        RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

        int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();

        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}
```

}

and adding it  like this recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDecorator(this));

and for ripple effect simply add  ?attr/selectableItemBackground to the recycler view's layout.

Comment: is it not possible to define both in the xml files?